# e.CloseReason with Visual Basic 2010 WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I saw, that's imposible, that not exist with visual basic wpf, but I need to cancel **any** close reason except when user end sesion, restar or shutdown the computer, all everything, I want to cancel and ask to the user if user wants continue, allow it I can cancel almost all close reasons with e.Cancel = True but when user opens Task Manager and on the process tab click on finish it, my application dies instantly :( I need to cancel any close reasons, included any application wants to kill mine, or cmd with taskkill, but I need to cancel all close reason, except I said, and the others, when cancel it ask for the user, I saw that's posible with c#, but I can't use it, I need do it with visual basic 2010 wpf applicaction, If anybody knows it, thanks :)
[Sorry for my bad english]
Best regards.

Comment: Why do you want to annoy your users?

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent your application from being killed. Not in C# and not in VB.NET or any other language.
What ever you saw in C# must have been something else. If you post the code, we can tell you, what it really does.

Comment: The code is in that web: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/549a4bbb-e77b-4c5a-b724-07996774c60a/ I think that is c#, but I don't know exactly, this code returs the close reason, but the kaspersky, when I try to kill it, appears a message one from taskmanager said access denied and other from kaspersky and said the same, that is posible, I don't know how, but posible is, If anybody can helps me, I'll tank you. Best regards.

Comment: The close reason `EndTask` is not used when you kill the process. Access denied means that the process is running under a user account you don't have the rights to kill processes in.

Comment: Then, how can denied the access for kill my app? It's posible?

Comment: Then, how Kaspersky (or other anti-virus) can do it?